# How to make an http call in parent component to setState and then send the state to all child components?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

So I am trying to make call axios.get('{link here}') from componentDidMount() of parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
       stuff: []
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
     axios.get({link})
     .then(res => {
         this.setState({stuff: res.data}) 
     }
}

render() {
    return(
    <Child stuff={this.state.stuff} />
    )
}
```

Then there is Child various child components, one of which is like:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
    }

    render() {
       return(
           //To access everything in the data of parent here in child component
       )    
}
```

Even though the parent shows data in console.log(), the child is not receiving anything

Comment: Add a .catch in your axios call. Code seems to be ok so maybe the axios call is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the class `Child` you can access the props that were passed down using `this.props`. It would look something like this:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: 'Felix'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child name={this.state.name} />
    )
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <p>My Name is {this.props.name}</p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If the child component is not going to hold internal state, then you can refactor it into a functional component:

```
function Child(props) {
  return <p>My Name is {props.name}</p>
}
```

More info about function and class components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).

Comment: after making the http request, the value is updated, but what gets passed to the child is the same initial value and the new value never gets sent. How can I fix this?

Comment: If data is actually being retrieved, add `{JSON.stringify(this.props.stuff)}` inside the child component. This will help you visualize the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the whole solution, but replace

```js
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
       stuff=[]
   }
}
```

by

```js
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
       stuff: []
   }
}
```

You have a `=` sign inside an object declaration.

Comment: I'm sorry that was just a typing error. What my aim is that a single HTTP call from parent and the data it gets can be passed to all children { data like company, client, product, all this comes from the HTTP call } so instead of making the request in every component I want to make a single request in parent and then pass down values. Failing to do so as the initial value is getting sent and not the value we get after the call. I hope I was able to clarify my issue